# Generate combinations from 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations

Let's say input array is

```
      [a0,a1,a2],[b0,b1], [c0,c1]
]
```

And expected output something like this

```
a0 b0 c0,
a0 b0 c1,
a0 b1 c0,
a0 b1 c1
a1 b0 c0,
a1 b0 c1,
a1 b1 c0,
a1 b1 c1
.......
a2 b1 c1
```

After writing out longhand these combinations I can sense patterns, like there are some fixed positions and then index moves from left to right, then left again and everything but cannot wrap my head around the multidimensionallity and how to implement? Loop inside loop inside loop, recursion or what? I am looking  for general directions.

Any suggestions and tips would be much appreciated

Comment: @GalAbra, op seeks a cartesian product, not a permutation.

Comment: Yeah! I knew solution would be connected to matrices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has a lot of recursive characteristics, but it's slightly more complicated than just permutations:

```js
const foo = [
  ['a0', 'a1', 'a2'],
  ['b0', 'b1'],
  ['c0', 'c1'],
];

function getCombinations(prefixArr, arr) {
  if (!arr[0]) return prefixArr;

  return arr[0].map((element) => getCombinations(
    [...prefixArr, element],
    [...arr].splice(1),
  ));
}

function getCombinationsWrapper(arr) {
  let ans = getCombinations([], arr);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    ans = ans.flat();
  }
  return ans;
}

console.log(getCombinationsWrapper(foo));
```